# How to automatically set column values from copied csv line on Google Sheets?

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I had this lines generated from a bash script,

```
2016,Feb,1
2016,Feb,2
2016,Feb,3
```

I want to copy it, maybe per line, and paste to google sheet.
And when I past it, it should automatically set the values based on the comma delimiter.

### Something like this in Google sheet after pasting:

### | year | month | day |

### | 2016 | Feb | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en).

If cell A1 has 2016,Feb,1 as value and you add to cell B2 the following formula

```
=SPLIT(A1,",")
```

you will see as result

```
   |      A     |   B   |   D   |   F   |
---+------------+-------+-------+-------+  
 1 |  2016,Feb,1|   2016|Feb    |      1|
---+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Then

1. Fill down until you get copied the above formula upto the last row.
2. Select columns B to F.
3. Copy and paste over the same range to get rid of the formulas.
4. Delete the column A.
5. Add the column headers.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you very much!